# My Protected Custom Setting seems to be null when I run the unit tests

Tags: unit-test, customsetting

I don't know much about Salesforce, but I've learned a lot these last few months. I was given the assignment to create an app for the Salesforce App Exchange, so that our API would be available inside of Salesforce.

When I first created the app, I put our API key inside of an Apex class. When I submitted the app for security review, this was rejected. I asked for advice on salesforce.stackexchange.com and I was told that sensitive data such as API keys should go into a Protected Custom Setting. Which I did.

So I ended up with code like this:

```
    Http httpProtocol = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse response;

// we need a string that looks like this: 
// /authtoken?user=lawrence@SameDay.com&pass=test1234
String authpoint = 'authtoken?service=salesforce&user=' + ps.SameDayUsername__c  + '&pass=' + ps.SameDayPassword__c;
    String endpoint = be + authpoint;

    request.setEndPoint(endpoint);
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    request.setHeader('x-api-key', PrivateIncInfo__SameDayConfiguration__c.getOrgDefaults().PrivateIncInfo__xApiKey__c);

try {
    // Send the HTTP request and get the response.
    // response.getBody() returns the JSON as a String.

        if (Test.isRunningTest() && (mock!=null)) {
            response = mock.respond(request);
        } else {
            response =  httpProtocol.send(request);
        }
```

This seemed to work, but now when I run the unit test, it is now failing on this line:

```
    request.setHeader('x-api-key', PrivateIncInfo__SameDayConfiguration__c.getOrgDefaults().PrivateIncInfo__xApiKey__c);
```

I get this error:

*System.NullPointerException: Argument 2 cannot be null*

So what is the normal way of dealing with this? How do I call this code and have it work in a test?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create the records. See also (emphasis mine):

> ## [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm)
>
> Starting with Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 24.0 and later, **test methods don’t have access by default to pre-existing data in the organization, such as standard objects, custom objects, and *custom settings data***, and can only access data that they create. However, objects that are used to manage your organization or metadata objects can still be accessed in your tests such as:
>
> - User
> - Profile
> - Organization
> - AsyncApexJob
> - CronTrigger
> - RecordType
> - ApexClass
> - ApexTrigger
> - ApexComponent
> - ApexPage

You can create an org default setting in a variety of ways. One such:

```
MySetting__c defaults = MySetting__c.getOrgDefaults();
defaults.SomeField__c = 'Some Value';
upsert defaults;
```